# nginx load balancer omits header

Tags: nginx

we have a setup where nginx is a load balancer for 2 apache tomcat webservers. When I make a request to a REST service through the load balancer, a certain header is always omitted when the request is forwarded to the tomcat servers.

```
curl -X POST -H Content-Type:text/xml -H Accept:text/xml -H api_key:secretkey -H Cache-Control:no-cache -d 'some date' http://load-balancer
```

The **api_key** header is always omitted. When I call the tomcat servers directly everything works as expected.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Could you please post your nginx configuration for the proxy pass-through? It's likely that you're missing a directive.

Comment: why are u sending it as a header not a post parameter?

Comment: Found the answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393772/how-to-get-non-standard-http-headers-on-nginx
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295808/header-variables-go-missing-in-production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here [How to get non-standard HTTP headers on nginx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393772/how-to-get-non-standard-http-headers-on-nginx) and [header variables go missing in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295808/header-variables-go-missing-in-production)

There is an option in the configuration to ignore headers with underscores in them.